# Stack Overflow Search giving incorrect results!

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

A bit strange to find, though on Stack Overflow, when I searched for the "Azure" keyword, it only yields **one result** - but when I searched again using "Windows Azure" (which also comprises "Azure" as a keyword), yields more than **22K results**!!!

***Search Result for - "Azure"***

[image: Search Result for - Azure]

***Search Result for - "Windows Azure"***

[image: Search Result for - Windows Azure]

Both above searches-results highlight tag **Azure** for each question (please see the screenshots) - and to my astonishment, when you click on any of the Azure Tag in search-results, it will again show only **one result** *again*!!

What's possibly wrong with these search results?

Answer (score 5):

**You have selected the 'featured' tab in your first search** (you had probably selected this on a previous search, and the setting has persisted). Currently, there's only one featured [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) question, so that's all that shows up.

Note  that when you searched for 'azure', the search engine assumed you meant the [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) tag, because it's an exact match. You can see that your search query has silently turned into [azure] and the header is 'Questions tagged [azure]'.

Your other search, 'Windows Azure', does not exactly match a tag, and so it searches for the text instead. As 'featured' is only a filter for tags and not for text, it seems to have defaulted to 'relevance', so you see all results.

Curiously you appear to be getting the old UI (notice the 'relevance', 'newest', ... being in a different style to the top screenshot) for the text search, and the new UI for the tag search. This has been [reported on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370132/6650102), but I get the new UI for both searches, strangely enough. That's probably because I'm a teams user and you aren't, so it looks like there's an inconsistency there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still curious about "azure" tag being part of many resultant-rows and when specifically clicked, yields only one resultant-row.

Comment: @AmitVerma Once again, it's caused by you having the 'featured' tab selected. You probably clicked it during some other search, but the setting is remembered. Just select another option (e.g. 'Newest') and you'll see all the results as expected.