# Tab style is inconsistent between normal pages and search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tab/page style is inconsistent between normal/category pages and search results.

Is this a conscious decision or is this still in progress? To me it feels like somebody forgot to update the search page, but maybe there is a good reason to style them differently, since their purpose is not exactly the same.

[image: Button bar]
*The button bar, featured on most views*

[image: Tab bar]
*Tabs, as seen on the search results*

Comment: Oddly enough, for Teams users the search page *is* updated (I see the pill buttons in on the page you show in screenshot 2). Not sure if it's just been forgotten or still a feature in testing. I'm guessing the former, though.

Comment: the orange highlighting on the top of the tab accompanying the orange highlighting on the right of the left nav "tab" seriously bothers me because i mentally associate top/left and bottom/right. :(